# selenium web driver - css selector having variable and # gives error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium IDE using css

```
css=#${tid}_title > li.deleteTitle.listDelete
```

the test runs fine in IDE

In selenium2

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#" + tid +"_title > li.deleteTitle.listDelete")).click();
```

it gives an error in webdriver

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: timeout
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
```

Sorry if this is a silly question

Comment: I can only say, that string concatenation is correct. The problem is in your previous steps. If this is an item in dropdown, you should expand this dropdown first

Comment: no it is not a drop down list. I am trying to record deleting the title. I hover the mouse over in action column - once i see the delete icon i click it.                                                                    <td>
    <ul id="77939_title" class="actionList">
    <li class="getPara" title="Get title URL">
    <li class="edittitle listEdit" title="Edit this title"></li>
    <li class="deletetitle listDelete" title="Delete this title"></li>
    </ul>
    </td>

Comment: You might want to try `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait();` [The docs.](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

Comment: Hi, I am trying                                               
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
    Actions hover = builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#78089_title > li.deleteTitle.listDelete"))); 
    hover.perform();  
I get an error of 
    org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector #78089_trait > li.deleteTitle.listDelete is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
   [Exception... "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12" nsresult: "0x8053000c (NS_ERROR_DOM_SYNTAX_ERR)"

Answer (score 2):

```
By.cssSelector("ul[id='"+tid+"_title'] > li.deleteTitle.listDelete"
```

works